# SimpleDateFormat changes the month in the date object

Tags: java, date

I've got a `datepicker` where i insert date of birth, for example `"1994/03/26"` as a string.

In backend i want to change the dateformat by parsing my string to a date object and then changing the format like this:

```
Date dateOfBirth1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd").parse(client.getDateOfBirth());//1994/03/26
String dateOfBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(dateOfBirth1);
```

The problem is: `dateOfBirth` changes the date to `26/01/94`, when it should be `26/03/94`.

Why does this happen? any help is appreciated

Comment: Have a look at the formats: you're using `mm` and `MM`. If you read the documentation one is for minutes and one for months - IIRC `MM` is the month so your first format should be `"yyyy/MM/dd"`. Your format interprets `03` as the minute and hence the month is assumed to be January.

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe is some mistake about "mm" and "MM"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mm` is minute, not month and you have the format `yyyy/mm/dd` on your first line. So what you really are parsing is *year/minute/day*.

What you are looking for, as you have correctly written on the second line, is the format for month: `MM`. The correct date format in your case will be `yyyy/MM/dd`. To get the expected behavior, change your code to

```
Date dateOfBirth1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").parse(client.getDateOfBirth());//1994/03/26
String dateOfBirth = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy").format(dateOfBirth1);
```

[SimpleDateFormat Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

Comment: Thank you sir! :)

Answer (score 1):

This beh. is correct, mm and MM have different meaning in the SimpleDateformat... So you are changing Minutes and Month information in the pattern you give the **SimpleDateformat** object

```
SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd")
```

and

```
SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yy")
```